# I'm trying to make some code that in an embed says the role and everyone that has it. This seems to not work though

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {Client, MessageAttachment} = require('discord.js');
const bot3 = new Client();


const mark2 = '*info personal'
const mark3 = '*info guild'
const mark4 = '*info roles'
bot3.on('message', msg =>{

    if (msg.content.startsWith(mark2)){
        const hashitag = msg.author.id
        const actualhashitag = msg.author.discriminator
        const evenbetterhashitag = "#" + actualhashitag 
        const personalembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Stuff about you')
            .setImage(msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setColor('#D11111')
            .addField('Your username',  msg.author.username)
            .addField('Your hashtag', hashitag, true)
            .addField('Your actual hashtag', actualhashitag, true)
            .addField('Your even realer hashtag', evenbetterhashitag, true)   
            .addField('Your amount of friends', 'Discord bots can not know that sadly')
            .addField('Your role', msg.member.roles.cache.map(role => role.name).join(", ") )
            .addField('Your role id', msg.member.roles.cache.map(role => role.id).join(", ") )
            .addField('Your nickname', msg.member.nickname);
        msg.channel.send(personalembed)
    }
    if (msg.content.startsWith(mark3)){




        const guildembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

            .setTitle(msg.guild.name)
            .setImage(msg.guild.iconURL())
            .setColor('#97FF00')
            .addField('the id of the server', msg.guild.id)
            .addField('the owner', msg.guild.owner.user.username)
            .addField('the owner tag', msg.guild.owner.user.tag)
            .addField('the owner id', msg.guild.ownerID)
            .addField('the owner nickname', msg.guild.owner.nickname)
            .addField('all roles', msg.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.name).join(", ") ) 
            .addField('the bots', msg.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.tag).join(' | '))
            .addField('the bots actual name', msg.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.username).join(' | '))
            .addField('the bot ids', msg.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.id).join(' | '))
            .addField('the bots hashtag(without the hashtag)', msg.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.discriminator).join(' | '))
        msg.channel.send(guildembed)

    }  

    if(msg.content.startsWith(mark4)){
        const whatrole = msg.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.name)
        const what = msg.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.id)
        const whatrolio = whatrole.length
        const roleembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('All roles and the people with the roles')
            .attachFiles('./stuff/role5.png')
            .setImage("attachment://role5.png")
            .setColor('FFA737')
        for (let step = 0; step < whatrolio; step++){
            let a = `role${step + 1}`

            roleembed.addField(a, whatrole[step])
            roleembed.addField('The people in this role', msg.guild.roles.cache.get(what[step]).members.map(stuf => stuf.user.username).join(' | '))
        }
        msg.channel.send(roleembed)
    }


})

bot3.login(process.env.token3)
```

The end is where I get a problem. I'm trying to with a loop write for every role all the members that have it. Here's what happens though. I get these error messages in heroku.

```
2020-06-17T18:46:33.705443+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-06-17T18:46:34.519478+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-17T18:46:36.795740+00:00 app[Worker.1]: This bot is online
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416763+00:00 app[Worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:425
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416816+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416819+00:00 app[Worker.1]:                 ^
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416820+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416822+00:00 app[Worker.1]: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416823+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Function.normalizeField (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:425:23)
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416824+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:445:14
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416824+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416825+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Function.normalizeFields (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:444:8)
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416825+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at MessageEmbed.addFields (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:259:42)
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416825+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at MessageEmbed.addField (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:250:17)
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416826+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Client.<anonymous> (/app/indexzues.js:66:23)
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416827+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416828+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at MessageCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416829+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) {
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416829+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
2020-06-17T18:46:49.416830+00:00 app[Worker.1]: }
2020-06-17T18:46:49.472687+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-17T18:46:49.513704+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in this line in the end

```
roleembed.addField('The people in this role', msg.guild.roles.cache.get(what[step]).members.map(stuf => stuf.user.username).join(' | '))
```

How do I make it display everyone with the role? The line before it is not the problem. It shows when I remove this line. So what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const what = msg.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.id)
```

This line is causing the error. Mapping a collection will only return an array containing the IDs, in your case.

```js
["1542312436436435", "4563497864379634", "43564376394764964"]
```

No other properties.

You can use the method below to get the members in a role:

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID").members.map(member => member.user.tag).join(" | "))
```

As an answer to your comment, this is how you can see the members for each role in the guild:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "*info roles") {
        const Embed = new discord.MessageEmbed();
        message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => { // Looping through each role in the guild.
            if (role.name == "@everyone") return false;
            if (role.members.size == 0) { // The role has no members.
                Embed.addField(`Members in ${role.name}`, `This role has no members.`);
            } else {
                Embed.addField(`Members in ${role.name}`, role.members.map(user => user.user.tag));
            };
        });
        message.channel.send(Embed);
    };
});
```

Without using embeds:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "*info roles") {
        const Embed = new discord.MessageEmbed();
        message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => { // Looping through each role in the guild.
            if (role.name == "@everyone") return false;
            if (role.members.size == 0) { // The role has no members.
                Embed.setDescription(`${Embed.description} \n\n Members in ${role.name}: This role has no members;`);
            } else {
                Embed.setDescription(`${Embed.description} \n\n Members in ${role.name}: ${role.members.map(user => user.user.tag).join("; ")};`);
            };
        });
        message.channel.send(Embed);
    };
});
```

Comment: Ok so that means that 
``` 
const what = msg.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.id) 
``` 
is the error right. But then how am I supposed to get the roleid of the role that is in the loop. Am I supposed to just make an array for the roles and then right arrayname[step].id or something.

Comment: That makes sense. Now a bit of an unrelated question. Is there a way of writing plain text in an embed?

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Is there anyway of writing just a line of plain text without a title and without a picture in an embed.

Comment: Yes. Instead of using the addField() function you can concatenate the current embed description with the role information. I'll update my answer in a bit to show you an example.

Comment: So I searched up the descriptiion command. i got setdescription. In the example it's shown it's below the title. Is it always below the title because that's not what I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216186/discussion-between-jakye-and-mataldin).